# gcc compiles libavformat code, but g++ does not

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, libavformat

In order to determine the video duration for a given file, I use libavformat. My program looks as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/dict.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx = NULL;
    int ret;
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s <input_file>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    av_register_all();
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, argv[1], NULL, NULL)))
        return ret;
    int64_t duration = fmt_ctx->duration;
    int hours, mins, secs;
    secs  = duration / AV_TIME_BASE;
    mins  = secs / 60;
    secs %= 60;
    hours = mins / 60;
    mins %= 60;
    printf("Duration: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", hours, mins, secs);
    avformat_free_context(fmt_ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that while gcc compiles the code just fine, g++ does so without complaint as well but the created object file can neither be linked by gcc nor g++. Or to be more precise:

```
gcc -c duration.c
gcc -o duration duration.o -lavformat
./duration my_movie.mp4
```

works. But this

```bash
g++ -c duration.c # "works" as in "g++ does not complain"
g++ -o duration duration.o -lavformat # (gcc produces the same output after compiling with g++)
duration.o: In function `main':
duration.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `av_register_all()'
duration.c:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `avformat_open_input(AVFormatContext**, char const*, AVInputFormat*, AVDictionary**)'
duration.c:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `avformat_free_context(AVFormatContext*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

does not work. This leads me to the conclusion that g++  does not produce code that can be linked properly (in this instance).

I would really like to make this work with g++ because it is part of a bigger c++ project and it would be a bit of a mess always having to compile files that make use of this library with gcc instead. Does anyone know why g++ won't compile this program correctly?

Comment: Maybe a name mangling issue?  Try wrapping the includes with `extern "C"`

Comment: Sounds like you've got a problem with name-mangling. You could try sprinkling `extern "C"` around. Or, accept that C and C++ are distinct languages.

Comment: Why do you think c code should compile as a different language?

Comment: @Olaf: I don't see any evidence that the OP is confused about languages here.  The specific code posted is valid C++ and the problem is with the FFmpeg header files.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: 1) If the header files are for C, they must not be compiled with a C++ compiler. 2) From the posted lines, he tries to compile `.c` files as C++ (using g++). The C compiler is typically gcc, not g++. Enough evidence to suspect confusion.

Comment: @Olaf: I see, but imagine this being a code snippet in a function of a c++ class (which it actually is in my case). Wouldn't it be legitimate to compile it with g++ then?

Comment: @Olaf: Most C libraries I encounter have header files that can be used from C++.  FFmpeg appears to be an exception.  OP adequately explains point 2.  In the future, please try to provide constructive comments, rather than belittling comments.  This is covered in the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice (I point this out because this is a pattern of behavior I am seeing, not just because of this particular comment)

Comment: @ryan91: You cannot compile C with a C compiler. The `extern "C" wrapper in headers make the code C++ code, telling the C++ compiler to use the C ABI for the declarations. It still is C++.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: see ^. Those headers become C++ code due to the `extern "C"` wrapper. It is a matter of the ABI. But as you might notice, OP compiles the same code a C and C++, which is always a bad idea. You would not expect to C code to be compilable with a fortran compiler, either, would you?

Comment: @Olaf: The headers are valid C++ even without the `extern "C"` wrapper, they just happen to declare functions which are not implemented by the library.  In either case, information about linkage and ABI is what the OP needs, not some sarcastic comment about how C++ is a different language than C and how dare you confuse the two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error tells us all we need to know:

```
duration.c:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `avformat_open_input(AVFormatContext**, char const*, AVInputFormat*, AVDictionary**)'
```

The linker wouldn't know the type of the arguments unless it thought it was a C++ function.  So you need to do this:

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/dict.h>
}
```

Normally, the header files would have the `extern "C"` part in them.  The FFmpeg project doesn't seem interested in doing this.  Some of the headers may include C constructions which are not compatible with C++, as noted in [FFmpeg ticket #3626](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3626).

If you run into such problems, you would need to write a shim in C.

Comment: Oh boy, that was simple! I haven't seen this language construct before, but that did the job, thanks!